# Linux non-blocking sockets: how much data can be read before blocking?

Tags: linux, sockets, nonblocking

Relatively simple question: when doing, say, a recv() using Linux non-blocking sockets, is there a way to determine a priori how much data is available to be received?

It seems like I'm always going to end up doing an extra recv() call just to determine that I've drained all data.

Comment: If you could get that information, it would already be stale before you could act on it...

Comment: What do you mean 'before blocking'? It's a non-blocking socket. It won't block. You can just call `recv()` until EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK occurs. Unclear what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `ioctl()` with `FIONREAD` to get the number of unread bytes in the socket buffer.

However, that would be double system calls as well, and it still wouldn't guarantee that more data hasn't arrived before you call `recv()`.

But there is an easier way - you can call `recv()` and it returns the number of bytes actually read. You only need to repeat the call if the number of bytes actually read is the same size as your requested buffer. Even if you don't repeat the call, the next `select()` call would return whether there is still more data available to be read.

Comment: I'm pretty sure recv (like read) is free to give you as many bytes as it sees fit, and that just because it returns less than your buffer size doesn't mean it's out of data.

Comment: @rivenmyst137 : The Posix probably doesn't guarantee this, though I haven't seen any implementation which would behave otherwise. Anyway the combination of `recv()` and `select()` as described will work in any case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the MSG_PEEK flag in the `recv` to determine the current number of bytes to be read from socket buffer. If the application is waiting for a determined number of bytes before it can process the data, it can rely on `MSG_PEEK`. Data won't be rremoved from the socket buffer. But `ret` would be the same value if you were to read without `MSG_PEEK`.

`ret = recv(sd, buf, MAX_CALL_DATA_SIZE, MSG_PEEK);`

This method results in extra syscalls until as many bytes the application needs is in the socket buffer. Also, it is not guaranteed that more bytes would have arrived by the time you actually do the read the data into application.